# Authentication session timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using the built-in Identity framework offered by the MVC template in VS2013 .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I am using the feature more or less out of the box.  It has been working fine. Compared to other posts I have read, my web.config has:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

How do I set a time out period for authenticated sessions, that is, after the user has logged in?

Comment: This will help you:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: Yes, I had followed the steps in this article and it worked successfully for me. I just cannot figure out how to set a time out. Right now, the logged in session is valid forever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Owin authentication, you should have something like this on your `StartUp.cs` file within the `App_Start` folder:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        // here you go
        ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(60000000000)
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```